# Get the URL of the file I just uploaded via form in Django

Tags: django, file-upload

I have this model with a FileField

```
class Attachment(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='%Y/%m/%d/')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Uploading is done with this form

```
class AttachmentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Attachment
        fields = ['file']
```

and this js

```
function upload(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  var data = new FormData($('#attachment_form').get(0))
  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    type: $(this).attr('method'),
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
  })

  $('#id_file').val('')

  // send message to server
  chatSocket.send(
    JSON.stringify({
      command: 'send',
      room: currentRoom,
      // message: ??
    })
  )
  return false
}

$(function () {
  $('#attachment_form').submit(upload)
})
```

This part of my view handles the form

```
# form to upload attachments
  if request.method == 'POST':
    attachment_form = AttachmentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if attachment_form.is_valid():
      # file is saved
      attachment_form.save()
  else:
    attachment_form = AttachmentForm()
```

I am using this form inside a real-time chat application. What I want is the following: the user uploads a file, then the javascript will send a message to the websocket containing the URL of the newly uploaded file, so the server can broadcast the attachment to other users.

How do I get the URL of the file I just uploaded? Keep in mind I can't just construct it with `MEDIA_ROOT` + whatever the `upload_to` field says + filename, as for example if two files with the same name are uploaded, Django will fill the second one with a few characters at the end of the name.

Comment: Do you have a view that is handling file upload/form POST?

Comment: yes, thank you for pointing it out. I updated my post

Comment: So, what's the problem? Since Django changes the name of the file with the same name in same directory, it also saves this in database together with sub-directories?

Comment: I would personally construct upload_to as a fixed string, and then before uploading add sub directory as a dynamically generated part to a fliename.

Comment: I still dont 'understand how I'd get the path to the file

Answer (score 0):

if you have the object in django
you can do

```py
attachment.file.url
```

Comment: I can only access the uploaded file via ```request.FILES```

Comment: after you have upload the file
you will have had saved it in a an object right? attachment is that object

Comment: Sure. How do I find that object? The file is saved to the db by calling ```save()``` on the form. You don't directly reference an object.

Comment: You can always do   obj = attachment_form.save()  , so you will get reference to save object in obj

Comment: as @BrankoRadojevic said then you get the url using obj.file.url